# How can I implement localization as a JSON object in a .Net EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, nuget, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.1, asp.net-core-localization

I am making a `Web API .Net Core 3.1` application that serves data from a MySQL database with `OData` protocol.

**My question is how can I add internationalization functionality (i.e. `i18n`) to a specific column without any foreign keys, by using `JSON` structure?**

For example I would like to define an entity model like this:

```
    public partial class City
    {
        public City(){}

        public ulong Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CountryId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    }
```

and then the data in `Name` column would be stored like the following for `en` and `de` locales:

```
{"en":"Cologne","de":"Köln"}
```

And then when the current locale is `de` the `Köln` and when the `en` is set as the current locale then `Cologne` fetch in the time of reading data!

Also when we store the data, the passed string is stored in the relevant property in the JSON format. For example if the locale is set to `es` and user passes `Kolne` then we have to have the following data in the DB:

```
{"en":"Cologne","de":"Köln","es":"Kolne"}
```

What I am looking for is some solutions like [this one](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable) which is suggested for Laravel and store the translations exactly in the way that I explained (i.e. in a JSON object and in a single column without any foreign keys)!

I am looking for some kind of NuGet that do this process automatically.

*Please notice this question is not about i18n JSON files!!! and is about JSON objects in database!*

Comment: Here is [a sample](https://damienbod.com/2016/01/29/asp-net-core-1-0-using-sql-localization/) of an old-fashion way of doing localization that uses a localization table and normally is not efficient as in the queries it needs lots of joins! And I am not looking for!

Comment: Maybe can use [this library](https://github.com/Innofactor/EfCoreJsonValueConverter) with some tricks!?